# Why does PHP-FPM for CentOS 7.2 have 2 www.socks?

Tags: php, centos

I've installed php-fpm from the standard repo, but I have a www.sock in both /var/run/php-fpm AND /var/php-fpm

Is this intensional? Which sock should I be using?

Comment: Most likely one of these is a symlink to the other one.

Comment: Nope, both are different.